# Infinite scrolling MySQL PHP jQuery - duplicate results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, infinite-scroll

Helly guys! I have built an app that retrieves new items from multiple RSS feeds every 2-3 minutes and stores them into a DB. I am trying to display the content of the DB using an 'infinite scroll' effect (using jQuery). All works fine, except after a few 'pages/scrolls' it sometimes displays duplicate entries, because the DB is being updated constantly with new content.

Here are the files I'm using (adapted from [Mik Ted's solution for Wordpress](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/01/scroll-pagination/)):

**Index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Scroll Pagination</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="jquery.js"> </script>
        <script src="javascript.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/vue1oix.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

        <style type="text/css"></style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#content').scrollPagination({
                    nop     : 10, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
                    offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
                    error   : 'No More Posts!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                                                // displayed. You can change this if you want.
                    delay   : 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                                   // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
                    scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                                   // but will still load if the user clicks.
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Ajax.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('inc/conn.php');   

    $offset = is_numeric($_POST['offset']) ? $_POST['offset'] : die();
    $postnumbers = is_numeric($_POST['number']) ? $_POST['number'] : die();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT ".$postnumbers." OFFSET ".$offset;

    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) 
    {
        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            echo '<h1>' . $row["ID"] . ' - ' . $row["Titlu"] . '(' . $row["Data_citire"] .')</h1>';
            echo '<h3>' . $row["Sursa"] . '</h3>';
        } 
    }

     /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

**Javascript.js**

```
function($) {

    $.fn.scrollPagination = function(options) {

        var settings = { 
            nop     : 10, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
            offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
            error   : 'No More Posts!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                                        // displayed. You can change this if you want.
            delay   : 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                           // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
            scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                           // but will still load if the user clicks.
        }

        // Extend the options so they work with the plugin
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        // For each so that we keep chainability.
        return this.each(function() {       

            // Some variables 
            $this = $(this);
            $settings = settings;
            var offset = $settings.offset;
            var busy = false; // Checks if the scroll action is happening 
                              // so we don't run it multiple times

            // Custom messages based on settings
            if($settings.scroll == true) $initmessage = 'Scroll for more or click here';
            else $initmessage = 'Click for more';

            // Append custom messages and extra UI
            $this.append('<div class="content"></div><div class="loading-bar">'+$initmessage+'</div>');

            function getData() {

                // Post data to ajax.php
                $.post('ajax.php', {

                    action        : 'scrollpagination',
                    number        : $settings.nop,
                    offset        : offset,

                }, function(data) {

                    // Change loading bar content (it may have been altered)
                    $this.find('.loading-bar').html($initmessage);

                    // If there is no data returned, there are no more posts to be shown. Show error
                    if(data == "") { 
                        $this.find('.loading-bar').html($settings.error);   
                    }
                    else {

                        // Offset increases
                        offset = offset+$settings.nop; 

                        // Append the data to the content div
                        $this.find('.content').append(data);

                        // No longer busy!  
                        busy = false;
                    }   

                });

            }   

            getData(); // Run function initially

            // If scrolling is enabled
            if($settings.scroll == true) {
                // .. and the user is scrolling
                $(window).scroll(function() {

                    // Check the user is at the bottom of the element
                    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $this.height() && !busy) {

                        // Now we are working, so busy is true
                        busy = true;

                        // Tell the user we're loading posts
                        $this.find('.loading-bar').html('Loading Posts');

                        // Run the function to fetch the data inside a delay
                        // This is useful if you have content in a footer you
                        // want the user to see.
                        setTimeout(function() {

                            getData();

                        }, $settings.delay);

                    }   
                });
            }

            // Also content can be loaded by clicking the loading bar/
            $this.find('.loading-bar').click(function() {

                if(busy == false) {
                    busy = true;
                    getData();
                }

            });

        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

I think the solution could be to drop the $offset query and instead use something like the following in my Ajax.php file:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM News WHERE ID < ".$id_of_last_item_on_page." ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT ".$postnumbers; /* No OFFSET*/
```

This way, the query will use the ID of the item last displayed as a start for the next page, in descending order (advancing towards 'the bottom' of the DB), regardless of the new entries being stored 'at the top' of the DB, thus eliminating the duplicates ([a solution](https://www.percona.com/files/presentations/ppc2009/PPC2009_mysql_pagination.pdf) by Yahoo back in 2009). But I don't know how to modify the three files in order to achieve that.

Any ideas on how to do it? I've spent days tweaking the code to no avail... Thank you very much!

Comment: assuming the posts v.s. ID are always going to be incrementing, and not jumping all over the place, you'd probably be better off having a `select ... where id > $last_displayed_id order by id asc` instead of normal `limit offset,quantity`.

Comment: You are right, that was my idea, too. The tricky part for me is to implement the code... 